How to share flask session to plotly dash application?
Can some help me out in finding a probable solution of using flask session in plotly dash application callbacks, thank you.
Flask app code - 

@app.route("/check", methods =["POST"])
def check():
    username = request.form.get("email")
    password = request.form.get("password")
    if username == "nimit.gupta@hotmail.com" and password == "123":
       session["username"] = username
       return redirect("/dash_app/")
    else:
       return redirect("/login")

Dash app code - 

dapp = Dash(__name__, requests_pathname_prefix="/dash_app/")

dapp.layout = html.Div(children = [
                                  html.H4(id = "text-output"),
                                  html.Div(id = 'none', children = [], style = {'display' :   None})  
                                  
                              ])

@dapp.callback(Output("text-output", "children"), Input("none", "children"))
def text_display(none):
    print(session.get("username"))
    return session.get("username")`

The problem is session.get("username") is empty. I want to use username to pass into query to get the information about that particular user, thanks.

if you run it as two separate applications then they can't share objects. it may need to keep data in database and use unique ID to get data. And it may send ID in cookies or in URL.
